# Lightbox doesn't show images loaded by entity_metadata_wrapper

Tags: nodes, media, entities, javascript

There is a field collection in a content type, it's name is `field_jeld`. This field collection has an image field, it is `field_image`. I also defined an image style called `book_mini`. I need to load the images using lightbox, to do so I set the following image format in manage display of every display mode:

[image]

I have to load the images in the front page so I used entity metadata wrapper, this is my code:

```
$nid = "A NID GET FROM SOMEWHERE ELSE";
$node = node_load($nid);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node',$node);
$jelds = $wrapper->field_jeld->value();
foreach ($jelds as $jeld){
    $item_id = $jeld->item_id;
    $fc_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $item_id);
    $photo_field = $fc_wrapper->field_image->value();
    $image = theme('image_style',
        array(
            'style_name' => 'book_mini',
            'path' => $photo_field['uri'],
        )
    );
    print $image;
}
```

This code prints the image in *book_mini* format very well but the problem is, when I click on it, it is not loaded by lightbox and no popup is shown, in fact the image is not a link. How do I can solve this problem?

---

**UPDATE1**

I also tried this

```
$nid = "A NID GET FROM SOMEWHERE ELSE";
$node = node_load($nid);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node',$node);
$jelds = $wrapper->field_jeld->value();
foreach ($jelds as $jeld){
    $item_id = $jeld->item_id;
    $fc_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('field_collection_item', $item_id);
    $photo_field = $fc_wrapper->field_image->value();
    $image = theme('image_style',
        array(
            'style_name' => 'book_mini',
            'path' => $photo_field['uri'],
        )
    );
    $name = $photo_field['filename'];
    $url=  $base_url."/sites/default/files/image/".$name;
    print "<a href='".$url."' rel='lightbox'>".$image."</a>";
}
```

I'm sure the `$url` points to the right file, after clicking the browser opens the lightbox but it doesn't show image, only white screen!

---

**UPDATE2**

The only solution I found is to use **filed collection views** and **Views**. I created a View called *loadcover* and selected `field_jeld` as a field. I also created a View of *field collection views*, called *fc_jeld*, and selected the required fields. This is the Formatter configuration of `field_jeld` :

[image]

Then using this code

```
print views_embed_view("loadcover","block",$nid);
```

it worked ! sounds the lighbox works with field collection only in the Views not the node!!!

Answer (score 0):

In the lightbox configuration settings it allows you to define a certain class, so it popups whenever an image has that certain class. So all you have to do is to find a way to add a class to your image.

Perhaps you could use the [Image URL Formater](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) module. Set your image field format to url. (So when it prints, it will print the image url instead of the actual picture)

then concatenate a string to add html to your code.

```
print '<img src="' . $image . '" class="lightbox">';
```

Comment: I updated the question. Ok I try your solution

Comment: I think you could also use `rel="lightbox"` aslong as the rel is inside the `<img>` tag.

Comment: But lightbox uses the `rel` inside the `a` not `img` https://www.drupal.org/node/356124

Comment: oh yes, you're correct.

Comment: I tried *'attributes' => array('class' => 'lightbox', 'rel' => 'lightbox'),* but it didn;t work

Comment: Did you go to the lightbox configure settings and defined the class as lightbox?

Comment: Yes I tried it, but it didn't work! may be lightbox has some problem with field collection fields. because when I opened the node in `/node/nid` , the lightbox didn't open the image.

Comment: I personally use this lightbox http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ since I found the Drupal one to be very bulky in size. The .js file is like 4 times bigger. You don't need the `data-lightbox=` like it says on here. A simple `rel="lightbox"` should work.

Comment: But I use tinybox http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinybox2/ it is very handy and small size. very nice modal window and good window to display messages